# Block of "random" characters printed on every page and cli

Tags: magento2.2, magento2.2.6

Please advice, what can be a reason for encoded characters block output in every call to magento - both in website and in ssh console?

It looks like it was started after using inline translation tool.

What is printed as text before any actual output:

```
HR+cPobz03NXsVWwWyIL5aee9dpGJJY7sJ9CDlO1iDTclVd53b+2PBvdUT8PJ6YVs7N9rsZQsc9h
```
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HR+cP+JPvxSYFTouH61obCBJ6E7Uv2YbNL9SKXKDBbzXQOLMwKZs//jAcznPW2+LS24ZLyMnl+Xv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Comment: Some kind of php debugging points me to zend files loaded by /vendor/composer/autoload_real.php...

Answer (score 1):

The reason was in disabled Ioncube loader.